# Can't access Python from cmd unless on c: drive

Tags: windows, command-line, python, nas

This likely sounds like a stupid question, but I can't seem to access python from cmd unless the working directory is on the c: drive. Ultimately, I want to run a script on a network folder (z:), but python won't even execute from my secondary internal drive (d:)

example cmd window text:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\usrname>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

C:\Users\usrname>z:

Z:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Z:\>d:

D:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\>
```

calling other programs like pip works just fine, as well as many of the commands from cygwin (added cygwin/bin to %path%) Python however remains obstinate. Can someone explain to me why this may be happening?

edit: here's my %path%

```
C:\Users\usrname\Downloads>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\cygwin64\bin;C;\Python27\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you litereally added `cygwin/bin` to your path, then that's why it doesn't work.

That's a relative path, which will only work from the root of the drive on which that folder is present, i.e. `C:` on `C:\cygwin\bin`.

Otherwise, when on `D:`, Windows will search `D:\cygwin\bin` and happily report it's not there. Same goes for `C:\Users\usrname` where you claim to be, then `C:\Users\usrname\cygwin/bin` will be searched.

So I assume you added `/cygwin/bin` to your path, with a (back)slash in front. This will make it work, regardless of your current directory, as long as you're on the `C:` drive.

You need to add the absolute path to `%path%`, including the drive letter.

According to your edit, you have a typo in your python path:

```
C;\Python27\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10
```

The semicolon should be a colon. Please note that this does validate the above statements: this path entry means you have two path entries: `C` and `\Python27\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10`, the latter causing it to work from the `C:` drive only, as that's the only drive containing that directory.

Comment: nope, I include c: in all my path entries...

Comment: Well show in your question what `%path%` looks like then, or how exactly you set it. I've just tested this, and without the drive letter it shows the behavior you describe.

Comment: also python is a separate entry from cygwin, as well as a separate env variable %PYTHONPATH%.

Comment: The command-line interpreter only looks in `%path%`, not `%PYTHONPATH%`.

Comment: it's also only python, all my cygwin commands work fine...

Comment: Sure, but that means there's something wrong with your python path.

Comment: ............ I found it -_- thanks ............ `;C;\Python27\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10`